# Android standard for educating users when requesting multiple permissions

Tags: android, permissions

I've been checking out Android's material design permission specification [here](https://material.io/guidelines/patterns/permissions.html#). To quote the document:-

> Critical permissions should be requested up-front. Secondary
>     permissions may be requested in-context.
>
> Permissions that are less clear should provide education about what
>     the permission involves, whether done up-front or in context.

In my case, my app requires three permissions during startup:two critical and one recommended. These permissions have to be accepted/denied before the app can operate and two or more need explanation. I'm wondering what the design standard is for educating users on multiple permissions. This is the flow I thought I might follow:

- Display a large dialog requesting access to three permissions and why access is needed for each. If the user clicks continue, they are presented the permissions one by one. If they decline either of the two critical permissions, the app displays a page giving the user an option to either update app permissions in Settings or Exit the app.

Is this a standard protocol to follow, or does Android recommend something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Android" (the OS) does not recommend anything. Google provides quite a lot of material, and maybe you already read ["Permission Usage Notes"](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/usage-notes.html) on developer.android.com

In my opinion you could first show an explanation and then ask for all of your critical permissions in one step. Why in one step ? Because it's less clicks for the user AND if users don't want to grant those permissions, you can react and politely inform them that without all of the aforementioned permissions the app won't be very useful.

For the "recommended" permission, one could ask for it as soon as the user tries to do something for which this permission is "locally critical".

There is a method which may be of use:

> To help find situations where the user might need an explanation,
>   Android provides a utiltity method,
>   `shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale()`. This method returns true if
>   the app has requested this permission previously and the user denied
>   the request.

(quoted from [developer.android.com: "Requesting Permissions at Run Time"](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html))